# iOS - Get Precise GPS Location After Entering Geofence

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, locationmanager, location-services

In my app I would like to start GPS tracking when a user enters a geofence and stop the tracking when a user exits. I have gotten the geofences to function, and when the app is in the foreground, the location manager receives continuous location updates while the user is inside the geofence until the user exits. The fences also function in the background - the app continues to send notifications regarding geofence entry and exit even when closed.

The problem I’m having is that while the GPS tracking works properly when the app is in the foreground when entering the geofence (if the app is put into the background after this, location updates still work), if the app is in the background or closed when entering the geofence, then the location manager only receives updates for a few seconds and then the tracking seems to cut out.

I would like to make it so I can get precise location information after entering a geofence even when the app is in the background or closed and have found conflicting information whether this is even possible. Is there anyway to cause the app to keep receiving location updates if the geofence is entered while the app is in the background?

Comment: 1. AFAIK there isn't anyway. All you can do is to show them a localNotification and upon tapping that and opening the app you can start the normal location Tracking again.

2. You also said: _then the location manager only receives updates for a few seconds and then the tracking seems to cut out._ I 'think' that's because for any app that has geofence set up...it will turn the app on for a few seconds...just to see if it has entered the region or not and then...during that time you may get normal location updates...but you have no control over that.

Comment: Start significant location tracking when your app is in the foreground and leave it on.  You should then be able to start GPS-based location updates in the background.